# Bind .position() function to $(window).resize() event

Tags: jquery

I have fully working jQuery code below that uses UI position plugin to position icons in a webpage based on offsets,etc.

While this one is working, I encounter some issues when resizing the browser and that the icon positions are not being recalculated.
   How to bind .position() function to  $(window).resize() event for the code below?

```
(function($) {
$(window).load(function(event) {


if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0 && $(title_class_selector).length !== 0  ) {

$(title_class_selector).position({
my: "center",
at: cornerPosition,
    offset:"<?php echo $x_coordinates_foradjustment;?> <?php echo $y_coordinates_foradjustment;?>",
of: $(element_selector)

});
}

    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have tried putting:

```
$(window).bind('resize',event);
```

Just before closing jQuery and it did not help.
Thanks for any tips..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you move the position handling to a seperate function, and then bind that function to both the `load` and `resize` events:

```
var doPosition = function(e) {
    if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0 && $(title_class_selector).length !== 0  ) {

        $(title_class_selector).position({
            my: "center",
            at: cornerPosition,
            offset:"<?php echo $x_coordinates_foradjustment;?> <?php echo $y_coordinates_foradjustment;?>",
            of: $(element_selector)

        });
    }
};

$(window)
.load(doPosition)
.resize(doPosition);
```

**NB: I strongly suggest you debounce the resize event, or it will fire lots of times**. This means that when the user has stopped resizing, the event will fire once instead of lots of times *during* resizing. See more here http://www.hnldesign.nl/blog/debouncing-events-with-jquery/

I created a simple fiddle (using an alert instead of your position calculating stuff, to show it works), with debouncing, [**over here**](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/3kG8q/)

Comment: This seems the right approach to me. `$(window).load(doPosition).resize(doPosition)` would be a bit more concise.

Comment: Thanks c_kick..I am studying your example..works great..cheers.